# Name of a book about Arthurian legends

Tags: story-identification, books

I once read a book that had a Arthurian background.

It was about a knight from the fellowship who now lived peacefully on an island. After this point some raiders come to the island and the knight (who is one handed) takes out his sword and goes to fight.

When he does he feels the army behind him riding into the war just like the old days. It has an alternative take on the legend of Arthur that they were young and foolhardy, and tried to make too much too fast and failed.

The book was written half as remembrances of the past and half present time scenes. There was mentions of war cries and I remember the name Cei. The book was British.

Can anybody remember what this book was titled?

Comment: FYI, Cei is simply the Celtic spelling of the name of Sir Kay.

Comment: The one-handed knight (and one of the few survivors after Arthur's death) is Sir Bedivere (Bedwyr in Welsh).

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3584973-cei-and-the-arthurian-legend